# selector using variable

Tags: jquery

Usually when I want to check if any child element inside a parent element was clicked I use something like this:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    alert($(e.target).is("#somediv *"));
}
```

But now I have the `somediv` in a variable. I have tried:

```
var somediv = $(this);
$(document).click(function (e) {
    alert($(e.target).is($(somediv, "*")));
}
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do that? Is it the best way to detect if a element or any child element was clicked?

Comment: It is an interesting question.. If you had a title as **'Check if an element belongs to a specific parent'** or something like that

Comment: @Vega feel free to change it. I will approve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No matter whether `somediv` is a DOM element or a selector, use [`.closest` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
if ($(e.target).closest(somediv).length > 0)
```

This will traverse the DOM up, starting at `e.target` and tests whether any ancestor (or the element itself) is `somediv`. If you want to exclude `e.target`, start at its parent:

```
$(e.target).parent().closest(somediv)
```

---

Another way, depending on the overall context, could be to simply bind the event handler to `somediv`:

```
somediv.click(function() {
   // click originated from inside the div
});
```

---

There is no easy way to create a selector from an existing DOM element. If `somediv` was containing a *selector* then you could use string concatenation to combine it:

```
$(e.target).is(somediv + ' *');
```

Comment: Does it work http://jsfiddle.net/GUAFW/1/? Is the fiddle different from what is in OP?

Comment: FelixKling I tested and understood you code. It works. Nice one. I just need to close a div if any other element outside the div is clicked, so somediv.click it is not the solution.

Comment: Why haven't you asked this then? ;) There are already quite a few questions targeting this, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element.

Answer (score 1):

Try below,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/GUAFW/2/

```
$(function () {
    var somediv = $('#container');
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        alert($(e.target).parent().is(somediv));
        //                   ^__ Just immediate childrens :(
    });
});
```

---

You can do `e.target != this` inside the handler to check if it is the parent or from child element.

**An Example:**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="child"></div><div class="child">
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').click(function (e) {
        alert(e.target != this);
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't see how it applies because what I want to know is: any given click is happening inside a div or any of the div childs or not.

Comment: @lolol Yea, it was a misunderstanding from my side.. I realized that after looking at Felix answer.

Comment: @FelixKling May be saving the best for the last :P

Comment: I just feel left out, I want comments on my answer too :D

Comment: I'm getting there! Your awnser is different, I need to do some follow up to understand it. =p

Comment: @Vega thank you for your help, but Felix code works nicely to my context and I don't need to do any extra checks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `someDiv` has the string literal identifier of the element, it won't be prefixed with `#`, so:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
  if ($(e.target).is("#" + somediv + " *")) {
    // some code
  } 
}
```

Comment: my bad, somediv is a dom element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.. Instead of .is() try using equality selector..

```
<div  class="hide"> 
    <span class="green" id="somediv"> YOOO </span>
</div>​

$('div').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target != this) {
        alert(((e.target.id) == 'somediv'));
    }
});​
```

[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Pv8Cw/1/)

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. It's a plugin and I have somediv on this.

Comment: I don't know the id. It's a plugin, I have to work with $(this).

Comment: In any case, did would check whether `e.target` is the element itself, not one of its descendants.

Comment: @sushanthreddy it was there to show that somediv is a dom element. now it's fixed. my bad again. =\